# How to use curl within business central (c/AL)

Tags: curl, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

How to post and get data from external url into business central AL codeunit using curl. Any other alternative method/approach is welcomed.

Comment: Readers may be able to help you fix your best attempt to solve your problem, based on reading of the BC documentation (or elsewhere). BUT questions ***Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*** are **off-topic**. Read here about [mcve] OR delete here and repost to [su] for general cmd-line help. Good luck.

Comment: Curl is bash/powershell application, I don't think there's a way tu run it from the AL code. However the answer from [ChristianBraeunlich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19688845/christianbraeunlich) is sufficient based on your needs. I encourage you to accept it, if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AL the [HttpClient Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/httpclient/httpclient-data-type) is what you are looking for when communicating between external systems, see: [Call external services with the HttpClient data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-httpclient)

```
    local procedure GetRequest() ResponseText: Text
    var
        Client: HttpClient;
        IsSuccessful: Boolean;
    begin
        IsSuccessful := Client.Get('https://httpcats.com/418.json', HttpResponseMessage);

        // error handling

        HttpResponseMessage.Content().ReadAs(ResponseText);
    end;
```

Modify the above example to your own needs. It's also a good practice to save URLs into their own variable with Locked = true and maybe even a placeholder:

```
var
    httpCatsUrl: Label 'https://httpcats.com/%1.json', Locked = true, Comment = '%1=http status code';
```

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBraeunlich for your response. Let me try this. I am calling a function within the wsdl, how will a post look like?